# Choice correspondence notation

Tags: choice-theory

My question is about the following notation:

I have noticed in several places (for example [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107458110) (page 15)  and [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~md3405/DT_Choice_15.pdf) (page 1)) that different authors use different notations for *choice correspondences*. Given a set $X$ of *objects that might be chosen* and a collection of non-empty subsets $\mathcal{A}$ of the power set of $X$, some use

1. $c:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow 2^{X}\backslash \emptyset$ (as in the second link)
2. $c:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow 2^{X}\backslash \{ \emptyset\}$ (as in the first link)

They both want to express that the co-domain of the choice correspondence must include all the *non-empty subsets* of the power set of X, i.e from any menu of options, you *must* choose something.

My question is, which one is the correct way to define it? Clearly, since $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$, both definitions cannot be equivalent.

My intuition would tell me that from the list above, (1) is the correct one. For example, if $X=\{\text{pasta (p)},  \text{chicken (c)}, \text{sushi (s)}\}$, then the power set of $X$ is:

$$
2^{X}=\Bigg\{\emptyset, \{p \},  \ \{c \}, \{s \},     \{p,c \}, \{p,s \} , \{c,s \}, \{ p,c, s\} \Bigg\}
$$

Since I want to “take out” the empty set from $2^{X}$ so that the choice from any non-empty subset of $X$ is itself non-empty, and since $\{\emptyset\} \notin 2^{X}$, it should be

$$
c:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow 2^{X}\backslash \emptyset
$$

Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"1." is wrong and "2." is correct, because (see e.g. [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html)):

$$A \setminus B = \{x: x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B\}$$

Say for example we have $S = \{a, b, c\}$ and $T = \{b,c\}$.

Then we'd write $S \setminus \{a\} = T$. We do NOT write $S \setminus a = T$.

And so in general, for *any* set $S$, $S\setminus \emptyset =S$.

We write $2^{X}\backslash \{\emptyset\}$ because $\emptyset \in 2^X$. In contrast, we have $2^{X}\backslash \emptyset = 2^{X}$.

**Example.** The set $S$ contains four elements: the empty set, an element called $a$, the set containing the empty set, and the set containing $a$.

$$
S=\Bigg\{\emptyset,a,\{\emptyset \},\{a \}\Bigg\}.
$$

Then we have:

$$ \begin{align} S \setminus \emptyset & = S 
\\ S\setminus\{\emptyset\}& = \Bigg\{a,\{\emptyset \},\{a \}\Bigg\}, 
\\ S\setminus\{\{\emptyset\}\}& = \Bigg\{\emptyset,a,\{a \}\Bigg\},
\\ S\setminus\{a\}& = \Bigg\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset \},\{a \}\Bigg\},
\\ S\setminus\{a,\{\emptyset\}\}& = \Bigg\{\emptyset,\{a \}\Bigg\},
\\ S\setminus\{\{a,\emptyset\}\}& = S.
\end{align} $$

The last equation is true because $S$ does not contain the set $\{a,\emptyset\}$.

See Enderton, in particular [p.3, top paragraph](https://books.google.com/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA3) -- it's well worth spending a little time if only on the first chapter.